# How to set a FAFontAwesome glyth to a tabBarItem in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome from Swift, Xcode 6 GM.

I can set a UIButtonItem's image using FA so I know the font is accessible and the code runs fine when called from Swift but I am failing to set an image for tabBarItem (I can change its title confirming I'm accessing the correct tab).

I have a UITabBarController which has a number of UINavigatorController, each with a UIViewController.

From my UITabBarController subsclass, within viewDidLoad():

```
let imageView = FAImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25))
imageView.image = nil
imageView.defaultIcon = FAIcon.FAFileTextO
(self.viewControllers?[0] as UINavigationController).title = "this line works!"
(self.viewControllers?[0] as UINavigationController).tabBarItem.selectedImage = imageView.image
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit and this enables:

... .tabBarItem.image = FAKFontAwesome.paperclipIconWithSize(25).imageWithSize(CGSizeMake(25, 25))